# Python cryptography slower when parallelized

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cryptography, multiprocessing

I'm working on a school project. I'm writing a script in python 3.7 to encrypt a huge number of photos ( tested with 130k, but i will use it for millions of photos ). I tried to parallelize it, but i got no performance improvements.

I split my data in 4 chunks ( i run a 4 core cpu ) and created a process for each chunk. I did that to get past the python global lock. I'm using AES for encryption.

```
import os
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import time
import multiprocessing
import threading
    
key = b"\xb2f\xff$j1\xc9\xec\x12\xa09\xa7\x7f\x16B\x93\x97~:\x9f\x1d\x1f\x907\x1c'\x0f\xf6A\xf5jf"
backend = default_backend()

def write(file, data ) : 
    with open( file, "wb", 6000 ) as writer : 
        writer.write( data )
        writer.close()


def encrypt_unit( file ):
    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).padder()
    
    with open(file, "rb") as reader :
        data = reader.read()   
        reader.close()
        
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    data = padder.update(data) + padder.finalize()
    
    encryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend).encryptor()
    message = encryptor.update(data) + encryptor.finalize()

    write( file, iv + message )

def decrypt_unit( file ):

    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).unpadder()

    with open(file, "rb") as reader :
        data = reader.read()   
        reader.close()
    
    iv = data[:16]
    data = data[16:]
    
    decryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend).decryptor()
    message = decryptor.update(data) + decryptor.finalize()
    
    
    message = padder.update(message) + padder.finalize()
    
    write( file, message )

def big_task( shouldEncrypt, file_list ) :
    for f in file_list :
        if shouldEncrypt : 
            encrypt_unit( f )
        else :
            decrypt_unit( f )

try : 
    
    path = "/home/codaruuu/Desktop/test"
    file_list = os.listdir(path)
    file_list = [ path + "/" + bit for bit in file_list if bit.endswith(".jpeg") ]
    
    N = 4
    M = len( file_list )
    PrList = []
    
    for i in range(N) :
        pr = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=big_task,
            args=(True, file_list[ (M // N ) * i : (M // N ) * ( i + 1 ) ] )
        )
        PrList.append( pr )
        pr.start()
        
    for pr in PrList :
        pr.join()
    
    
except Exception as err :
    print( err )
```

Here are my results for a data set of 130k photos (1.2 GB) :

```
time python3 myFile.py
```

For the parallelized version I get :

```
real    8m31,209s
user    0m39,571s
sys     0m22,260s
```

The sync version :

```
real    4m32,175s
user    0m24,382s
sys     0m13,653s
```

Do I miss something ? I mean, I dont think the difference is big enough. Have I used too little photos for my test  because those results seem wrong.

Comment: multiprocessing need extra time to start new process and send data to this process. It has to convert all data to pickle, save it in file, start process, read data from file and unplickle it. Maybe you should send numbers `M, N` instead of `file_list` - and read filenames inside process.

Answer (score 2):

`if __name__ == '__main__':` was an important omission as multi-processing restarts your script to run your function, re-running the attempt to spawn scripts :(. `try / except` masked this error.

I've replaced your big_task with a sleep time using your structure.

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def big_task(taskno):
    print(f"{time.time()} starting {taskno}")
    time.sleep(1.0)
    print(f"{time.time()} ending {taskno}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 4
    PrList = []
    for i in range(N):
        pr = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=big_task,
            args=[i]
        )
        PrList.append(pr)
        pr.start()
    for pr in PrList:
        pr.join()
```

And using a Pool which is nicer.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def big_task(taskno):
    print(f"{time.time()} starting {taskno}")
    time.sleep(1.0)
    print(f"{time.time()} ending {taskno}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 4
    with Pool(N) as p:
        p.map(big_task, range(N))
```

Essentially as per https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html